# How to find max or min Object in binary tree depends on specific field

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

My POJO object is

```
public class Order {
  int price;
  int size;
  boolean isBid;
```

I need to write 2 methods.
First should return Order with max price and isBid = true;
Second should return Order with min price and isBid = false;

P.S. This is Market Order Book, so object with isBid = true can't have price more than Object with isBid = false;

P.S.S. I choose binary tree as data structure, but maybe there are even better structure for this case.

Below you can see my method to add new Node

```
private Node updateOrderBook(Node current,Order order) {
  if (current == null) {
    return new Node(order);
  }
  if (order.getPrice() < current.order.getPrice()) {
    current.left = updateOrderBook(current.left,order);
  } else if (order.getPrice() > current.order.getPrice()) {
    current.right = updateOrderBook(current.right,order);
  } else {
    current.order.setSize(order.getSize());
  }
  return current;
}
```

So you can see my Tree is sorted based on Price;

Thank you for answer

UPD. My current solution is

```
private Order findBestBid(Node current) {
    if (current == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (current.order.isBid() && current.right == null) {
      return current.order;
    }
    
    return current.order.isBid()
        ? findBestBid(current.right)
        : findBestBid(current.left);
```

But it is not work if last find Order is Ask.
I understand that means i have to find the last found Bid (this is going to be the Best Bid)

But i don't understand how to do this.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Meaning: you have a binary tree **solely** ordered on the price property, ignoring the its other properties. So ... you probably have to iterate the whole tree ... and compare all entries to identify min/max. Given that this is probably your homework ... what exactly have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: Some things are not clearly stated, a simple language problem maybe. The `price` of an Order may no longer be changed, as then the tree structure is corrupted, possibly .

Comment: @GhostCat i make update about my current solution